# Get Response from GCM

Tags: php, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

How can i get Response if the Message was sent or Not, using Php Script, Then i want to use the Response to Determine If the Device is Online or Not,

Here is my Php Script to Send a Message :

```
function send_push_notification($registration_ids, $message) {

 $regId=$registration_ids;
 $msg=$message;
 $message = array("message" => $msg);

 $regArray[]=$registration_ids;
 $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

 $fields = array('registration_ids' => $regArray, 'data' => $message,);
 $headers = array( 'Authorization: key=API_KEY','Content-Type: application/json');

 $ch = curl_init();

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

 $result=curl_exec($ch);
 echo $result; 
 if($result==FALSE)
 {
die('Curl Failed');

}
 curl_close($ch);

 }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response your server gets from GCM server doesn't tell you if the message was sent or not. It only tells you if the message was accepted by the GCM server or rejected. If it's accepted, GCM server will try to deliver it, but there's no guarantee it would succeed. If it's rejected, you get an error message (such as `InvalidRegistration`, `MissingRegistration`, etc...).

If you want an acknowledgment of delivery, you must have code in your Android app that upon receiving of the message makes a call to your server, to acknowledge the message was received.

Answer (score 0):

You don't get response from the app; you can only get response from the GCM system itself. When the CURL call completes, `$result` contains a JSON-encoded object; its `id` property contains a message ID upon success.